# Creating an ICMP covert channel

Tags: python, scapy, icmp

How to send a custom echo reply when an echo request is received using scapy. Or whether we need to send an echo request when an echo request is received?

This is for academic purpose only.

Answer (score 0):

Your best option for this kind of job is to write an `AnsweringMachine`.

As ICMP echo request / echo reply is not hard, it should be easy to write it based on the class `ARP_am` in `scapy/layers/l2.py` (see https://bitbucket.org/secdev/scapy/src/tip/scapy/layers/l2.py?at=default#cl-500).

If you think it's too complicated for what you want, a quick-and-dirty option could use the `prn` parameter of the `sniff()` function to send a reply when a request is seen. Try this:

```
sniff(iface='eth0', filter='icmp', lfilter=lambda p: p[ICMP].type == 0
      prn=lambda p: send(
          IP(src=p[IP].dst, dst=p[IP].src)/ICMP(type=0)/p[ICMP].payload))
```